# Is there a product attribute that tracks when the last time a product was updated?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a script that we run that calculates a bunch of custom product attributes between several currencies.  The one flaw with this script is that it runs through literally ALL products in our database. At the moment we have ~5K products, but in the next few months we will be importing several databases's of other products that will bring us up to ~150K products. Obviously this script will suddenly take hours to complete.  I'm trying to figure out a way to only run the products that have been recently updated (within the past day or a set period of time). The only thing I'm not sure of (and can't pin down) is if there is a product attribute that records when the product was last "re-saved".

If anybody knows what this field is called (or if it exists), it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the database there is the column updated_at in the catalog_product_entity table. You should be able to grab that data with the following:

```
// Load the product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);

// Get updated_at attribute
$product->getUpdatedAt();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, thats exactly what I needed to know (albeit, I'm doing direct queries against the DB, and using this to select only products updated within the past date range).